# JOOQ with Gradle and Kotlin do not generate files

Tags: java, jpa, gradle, kotlin, jooq

I have the following gradle task in my `build.gradle.kts`. It's supposed to generate files from my JPA entities. However when running this task, upon succeeding, no file or directory is generated.

```
task(name = "generateJooq") {
    doLast {
        val configuration = Configuration().apply {

            generator = Generator().apply {
                database = Database().apply {
                    name = "org.jooq.util.jpa.JPADatabase"
                    properties = listOf(Property().apply {
                        key = "packages"
                        value = "com.example.sample"
                    })
                }

                target = Target().apply {
                    packageName = "com.example.jooq"
                    directory = "src/generated/java"
                }
            }
        }

        GenerationTool.generate(configuration)
    }
}
```

This is my entity living under package `com.example.sample`. Note that I wrote this entity in Java.

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column
    private String title;
}
```

Had the following logs

```
./gradlew clean generateJooq      

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

Comment: Possibly similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/43008349/521799

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that your `Book` class is in `src/main/java` correct?

And now you want that class to be available to `JOOQ` right? There's a bit of a chicken or egg problem where the Gradle buildscript classloader (which loads gradle tasks) is defined before `src/main/java` is compiled.

You'll need to pass a custom classloader to `JOOQ` (eg URLClassloader). `JOOQ` can then use the classloader to load the classes (hopefully the `JOOQ` API's support this). You can use `sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath` to create an array of `URL`.

I see that `GenerationTool` has a `setClassLoader(..)` method [here](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ-codegen/src/main/java/org/jooq/util/GenerationTool.java#L115). I'm guessing you'll call that

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45164073/1089967) for a similar solution (using `Reflections` rather than `JOOQ` but fundamentally the same).

Comment: That's probably it. [Here's a similar question where Maven is used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43008349/521799)